# Merge the [sequelize] and [sequelize.js] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) is a popular ORM library for Node.js.

It seems people are using both [sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequelize) (97) and [sequelize.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequelize.js) (457), which are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when, but this has been completed.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sequelize.js/info